# wx Python Menu affecting display

Tags: menu, wxpython

I have two fairly large python apps using wx python for the gui. The menu bar seems to affect the display in a way that I cannot understand. In one, the menu bar appears on Show, but it pushes down the remaining controls, and the bottom ones are half off the screen. I.e. Fit() does not seem to take the menubar into account.

On the second I have a similar problem, but here the menu bar does not appear until the cursor is placed on the main panel. Then the menubar appears and pushes down the remaining controls.

I've tried to produce a skeleton screen that duplicates the problem, but I cannot, so I'm looking for pointers as to the possible cause of the problem. Can anyone suggest where to try to solve it?

Comment: Possibly a parent - child problem? Maybe you have a window, a panel, and widgets that belong into the panel have the window as a parent.

Comment: Thanks Petr. I think You're right. I've been experimenting with various Fits and Layouts. The problem is that this was my first Python app, and I was learning as I did it. It is structured, but could be a lot better. I guess I need to spend a day re-engineering it from the ground up. But thanks for your insight. I'll bear the parent-child thing in mind as I work through it

Comment: I think it might be a Ubuntu version issue: works on 14.01 but not on 12.04. Work around by adding a border below the bottom item that includes the menu height. Then the display of the menu does not affect anything relevant in the display. Just looks odd as it jumps